# GIT - Resolving conflicts on the same repository from two computers

Tags: git

I'm in the process of merging the develop branch into a long dormant branch in order to revive it (rebase is not an option). I have over 900 conflicts in files and am trying to figure out if any of my colleagues can help. We're using windows with source tree & Git kraken as we need. Is there a way to resolve conflicts in parallel from two computers working on the same repo folder? I was thinking about working on the repo on my machine resolving conflicts while a colleague opens the same repo from his computer using a windows folder share of the repo. This way (I think) we both could work resolving conflicts in parallel (I start from the top, he starts from the bottom so we don't work on the same file).

Is this doable? Are there other ways to handle this with multiple people resolving conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Git kraken and I don't know how you plan to process the conflicts :

- manually by editing the source code ? (with a text editor for example)
- or using a integrated tool that helps to resolve conflicts ?

In the first case, as long as your colleague doesn't execute git commands from his laptop remotely (in other words, if he only solves conflicts file after file), I don't see why this approach wouldn't work.

If you use a tool that automates several things during the merge process and executes git commands in the background, it is probably more dangerous.

Note : if you are able to share your filesystem with your colleague with read-only access on the `.git` folder, it could be a good way to prevent from having bad surprises.

Comment: Both source tree & git kraken are windows UI over git. they run the git commands in the background for actions I do in the UI. for example over a file conflict I can open beyond compare and merge the file and when I close beyond compare I just have to move to the next file. I do not run any git command directly

reading the log of sourcetree it executes for every merge

 "git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks -c credential.helper= -c credential.helper=\"---path removed---" mergetool -y --tool=sourcetree -- Libraries/Base/packages.config